# Access comparing multiple columns for a result

Tags: ms-access

First I just wanted to say thank you for all your help. I have a new issue with the next step of my query.

- For each record there are three columns.  For sake of argument lets
  call them A,B and C.
- In each column there can be four results:  Pass, Not Tested, Low,
  High
- Not Tested and Pass can be treated as a pass.
- Low and High can be treated as a fail.

I would like to see a result in another column that if there are any fail statements in columns A, B or C a fail response will be shown.  Otherwise a Pass will be shown in the new column.

```
A------------B.---------- C.---------RESULT.-------
PASS---------PASS---------PASS-------PASS----------
High---------PASS---------PASS------ FAIL----------
Not Tested---PASS---------PASS-------PASS----------
LOW----------PASS---------PASS-------FAIL----------
```

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?  All you need to do is check if any of the three columns have a 'Fail' or 'Low' or 'High' to indicate failure.  Or you can flip the logic...

```
SELECT Table1.A, Table1.B, Table1.C, 
    IIf([a]='Fail' Or [a]='Low' Or [a]='High','Fail',
    IIf([b]='Fail' Or [b]='Low' Or [b]='High','Fail',
    IIf([c]='Fail' Or [c]='Low' Or [c]='High','Fail','Pass'))) AS Result
    FROM Table1;
```

Here is the flipped logic:

```
SELECT Table1.A, Table1.B, Table1.C, 
    IIf([a]='Pass' Or [a]='Not Tested',
    IIf([b]='Pass' Or [b]='Not Tested',
    IIf([c]='Pass' Or [c]='Not Tested','Pass','Fail'),'Fail'),'Fail') AS Result2
    FROM Table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the default value for ColumnD to "PASS", then run the following query:

```
UPDATE ATable SET ATable.D = "FAIL"
WHERE (((ATable.A)="high" Or (ATable.A)="low")) OR (((ATable.B)="high" Or (ATable.B)="low")) OR (((ATable.C)="high" Or (ATable.C)="low"));
```